# Get page load time in angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I am working on a angular project where I need to track the page loading time.
Is there any method in angular using which I can track page loading time.

Code that I tried:

```
var loadTime = window.performance.timing.domContentLoadedEventEnd - window.performance.timing.navigationStart; console.log('Page load time is ' + loadTime);
```

Comment: Please show us the code that you have tried.

Comment: var loadTime = window.performance.timing.domContentLoadedEventEnd - window.performance.timing.navigationStart;
    console.log('Page load time is ' + loadTime);

Answer (score 0):

You can use `setInterval` combined with `angular.element(document).ready()`.

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.7.5/angular.min.js"></script>
<script>var time = 0;
var stopwatch = setInterval(function() {
  time = time + 0.001;
}, 1);
angular.element(document).ready(function() {
  clearInterval(stopwatch);
  document.getElementById("text").innerText = "It has taken " + time + " seconds for this page to load.";
});</script>
<span id="text"></span>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answers. I was using 'window.performance.timing' but it is deprecated now. Is there any alternative method for this ?